# AnchorPane Constraints don't work

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

In application one FXML is loaded into tha AnchorPane of the other FXML. The problem is that the AnchorPane Constraints (exactly Bottom one) of ListView don't want to work during resizing.

The code of the file which is loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <HBox cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" fillHeight="true" minHeight="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="1280.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <children>
        <TabPane id="navPane" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" maxWidth="-1.0" minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="420.0" rotateGraphic="false" side="LEFT" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" tabMaxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" tabMinHeight="30.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
          <tabs>
            <Tab closable="true" text="Untitled Tab 1">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="homePane" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;">
                  <children>
                    <StackPane id="navPaneHeaderPane" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                      <children>
                        <AnchorPane id="navPaneHeaderPane" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="" />
                        <Label id="navPaneHeaderString" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" text="Label" StackPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                      </children>
                    </StackPane>
                    <TextField cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="294.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="28.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="28.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="55.0" />
                    <Separator cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="100.0" />
                    <ListView fx:id="listView" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" pickOnBounds="true" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="120.0" />
                  </children>
                </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane id="Content" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
              </content>
            </Tab>
          </tabs>
        </TabPane>
        <AnchorPane cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
          <children>
            <TableView cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="860.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Column X" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Column X" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </children>
      <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@../../../../skins/default.css" />
      </stylesheets>
    </HBox>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The code of the file where the above FXML is loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?scenebuilder-preview-i18n-resource ../lang/ru_RU.properties?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="mainStage" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="UI.PrimaryStageController">
  <children>
    <StackPane fx:id="toolbarStack" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1280.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="100.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <children>
        <FlowPane fx:id="toolbarPane" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1280.0" style="">
          <children>
            <Button id="fileButton" fx:id="selectorButton" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openSelector" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="%selectorButton" />
            <Button fx:id="fileButton" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openFileMenu" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="%fileButton">
              <stylesheets>
                <URL value="@../../skins/default.css" />
              </stylesheets>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="toolsButton" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openToolsMenu" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Button" />
            <Button fx:id="helpButton" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openHelpMenu" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Button" />
          </children>
        </FlowPane>
      </children>
    </StackPane>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="contentPane" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="100.0" />
    <Button cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeApp" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="%exitButton" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
  </children>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@../../skins/default.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

The first FXML is loaded into the AnchorPane with `fx:id = "contentPane"`. For reasons I don't know ListView `fx:id = "listView"` doesn't resize during window resizing. Any ideas?
P.S. I use JavaFX 8

Comment: you have to use widthProperty() of pane when pane is resizing you have to chnage in the sizing of list. i do this with these property